# How to use a query object in a Mongoose query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, server-side

I have a query object like this:

```
{$and: [length: {$gt: 10}, sentiment {$gt: 0.23}]}
```

Call this const q.

So I want to find all documents in a Mongo collection that fits these parameters (where the doc's "length" is greater than 10 and it's "sentiment" is greater than .23). What would the Mongoose query I write look like?

Comment: What you have tried? Always post your solution, and then your question.

Answer (score 0):

Query in mongoose will be

```
await CollectionName.find({
    {$and: [{"length": {$gt: 10}}, {"sentiment": {$gt: 0.23}}]}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
Collection.find({
    $and: [{"length": {$gt: 10}}, {"sentiment": {$gt: 0.23}}]
    }, function (err, results) {    
    ...
    }
```